Change the background color of AppShell buttons in .NET 8 MAUI
I would like to know how to change the background color of the AppShell menu buttons.
Is there a property I could use?
Is there a template that I could customize? like this :
(App.xaml of Platforms\Windows)
    <maui:MauiWinUIApplication.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="MauiAppTitleBarTemplate">
            <Grid>
                <Border Canvas.ZIndex="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="#0366d6" Margin="0,0,0,0"></Border>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </maui:MauiWinUIApplication.Resources>

Image below of what I want to change the background color of:

I expect this result :

Edit : 2024-06-30 :
I achieved the expected result, my approach was not the right one by using a template, here is the content of the file (App.xaml of Platforms\Windows) :
    <maui:MauiWinUIApplication.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style TargetType="ContentControl" x:Key="WindowChromeStyle">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl">
                        <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="#0366d6">
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ClientAreaPresenter" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</maui:MauiWinUIApplication.Resources>


Can you show me how you added those buttons(Code)

These buttons appear when using the AppShell class.
You will find an example: link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation?view=net-maui-8.0&viewFallbackFrom=net-maui-6.0#back-button-behavior

@Johann Camboly
The solution I found useful involves making changes at the Content Page level, and it's now working for me.
Here are the code changes I made:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="NewDemoApp.MVVM.View.MainPage"
             Shell.NavBarIsVisible="True"
             Title="MainPage"
             FlowDirection="LeftToRight"
             Shell.BackgroundColor="Red"
             x:Name="myMainPage">

    <Shell.TitleView>
        <Label Text="MainPage" 
               VerticalTextAlignment="Center" 
               HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" 
               FontAttributes="Bold" 
               FontSize="16" 
               VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
               HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
               BackgroundColor="Yellow" 
               TextColor="Red" />
    </Shell.TitleView>

</ContentPage>

The output now looks like this:

